# Rating site in PHP

Tags: php, rating

I'm planning on doing a rating site for hotels in a certain region. Before I reinvent the wheel, are there any complete open source rating alternatives that I just can install on my server?

I know I'm not being very specific, but some functionality that might be good is...

- Add details of a hotel
- Rate and comment a hotel
- Forum is good
- Use google maps to place hotels on a map (I'll perhaps have to fix that one myself)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the site, with the admin (adding hotels, including them on a map), and then under each hotel, include a [Disqus](http://disqus.com/) or [Intense Debate](http://intensedebate.com/) code snippet. I managed to evade a serious couple of hours of work this way (using Disqus).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Pligg](http://www.pligg.com/about/)?  It doesn't have everything you mentioned but maybe you could modify it to your needs.